# Join 3 tables in one column and sort them

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm completely new to SQL and need a bit of help.

I have 3 tables in my SQL Server 2008 database. In each table there are different kinds of users (coworkers, students, teachers). All of them have Nicknames. There is also a table with all users.

I would like to join all of them into one single table with one column called nickname. In this column the three different types of users are supposed to be sorted in packages like so regardless of their nickname:

coworker1 coworker2 coworker2 student1 student2 student3 teacher1 teacher2

I tried the following way:

```
SELECT A.Nickname, B.Nickname, C.Nickname, D.Nickname
FROM users AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN coworkers AS B ON
A.Nickname = B.Nickname
LEFT OUTER JOIN teachers AS C ON
A.Nickname = C.Nickname
LEFT OUTER JOIN students AS D ON
A.Nickname = D.Nickname
```

Well that does not work at all and gives me a table with 4 columns each full with NULLs and unsorted users

Thanks HABO this did it for me:

```
select Nickname from (
  SELECT Coalesce( B.Nickname, C.Nickname, D.Nickname, A.Nickname ) as Nickname,
    case
      when B.Nickname is not NULL then 1
      when C.Nickname is not NULL then 3
      when D.Nickname is not NULL then 2
      else 0 end as Package
  FROM users AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN coworkers AS B ON
  A.Nickname = B.Nickname
  LEFT OUTER JOIN teachers AS C ON
  A.Nickname = C.Nickname
  LEFT OUTER JOIN students AS D ON
  A.Nickname = D.Nickname ) as Elmer
order by Package, Nickname
```

Comment: Why don't you have a single table (users), and a column that indicates whether they are an employee, a teacher or a student?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the non-NULL column output:

```
SELECT Coalesce( B.Nickname, C.Nickname, D.Nickname, A.Nickname ) as Nickname
FROM users AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN coworkers AS B ON
A.Nickname = B.Nickname
LEFT OUTER JOIN teachers AS C ON
A.Nickname = C.Nickname
LEFT OUTER JOIN students AS D ON
A.Nickname = D.Nickname
```

Note that the columns have been rearranged so that the nickname from `users` is the last choice.

Your comment regarding sorting into packages is unclear to me. Do you mean something like this:

```
select Nickname from (
  SELECT Coalesce( B.Nickname, C.Nickname, D.Nickname, A.Nickname ) as Nickname,
    case
      when B.Nickname is not NULL then 1
      when C.Nickname is not NULL then 3
      when D.Nickname is not NULL then 2
      else 0 end as Package
  FROM users AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN coworkers AS B ON
  A.Nickname = B.Nickname
  LEFT OUTER JOIN teachers AS C ON
  A.Nickname = C.Nickname
  LEFT OUTER JOIN students AS D ON
  A.Nickname = D.Nickname ) as Elmer
order by Package, Nickname
```

Comment: You got me right! The second code is exactly the ne I needed! Thank you!

Comment: It works and I understand how it works but don't really know how to reproduce the part with "case ... when ... then 1 ... end as Package" 

Could you explain how the whole "packaging" works?

Comment: @user2966326 - `COALESCE` returns the value of the first non-NULL argument. It checks coworkers, teachers, students and then falls back on users as the last choice. The `CASE` checks to see which table supplied the nickname: `1` if it came from coworkers, `3` if teachers, `2` if students and `0` if users. The numbers were picked so that when you `ORDER BY` the number it will output the users together as you requested: coworkers, students, teachers. It could just as well have returned `'coworkers'`, `'students'` and `'teachers'` since you _happen_ to want them in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could just `union` and `order` your three user type tables instead of doing a bunch of joins.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT s.nickname nickname, ..., 'student' type FROM students s
UNION
SELECT t.nickname nickname, ..., 'teacher' type FROM teachers t
UNION
...
ORDER BY type;
```

Does this closer to what you are trying to accomplish?